# Imposible ejecutar desde NetBeans. KDE Neon 5.17

Tags: netbeans

Un saludo.

He creado un proyecto de NetBeans 11.0 LTS en un USB desde KDE Neon. Pues bien, puedo compilarlo y todo, pero al ejecutar, da un error. Lo he pasado el escritorio y ocurre lo mismo. El error es el siguiente:

```
/bin/sh: 1: exec: /home/pablo/Escritorio/Circulo/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/circulo: Permission denied

RUN FINISHED; exit value 126; real time: 0ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

Estoy ejecutando NetBeans como Root (a ver si así me dejaba), pero tampoco.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.
Gracias. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede ser un problema de permisos en la carpeta donde ejecutas el proyecto.

Prueba a darle permisos de lectura, escritura y ejecución a la carpeta que contenga el proyecto:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /ruta_a_tu_proyecto
```

"chmod" cambia los permisos

"-R" para que afecte a todas las subcarpetas (recursivo)

"777" para dar permisos de lectura, escritura y ejecución

y finalmente la ruta del directorio al que le quieres dar los permisos, por ejemplo "/home/pablo/Escritorio/Circulo"

Comment: Sí, eso me parece, por eso decía de hacerlo recursivo, para que le de permisos tambien a todo el contenido

Comment: Ah cierto, no lo ví :-)